# file name should be for class, Interface, service and other files in angular (small or big letter)?

Tags: javascript, angular, service, architecture, angular2-forms

What should be the **start file name(start with capital or small)** at the time of **creating architecture for angular2**.

for eg. in other technologies, we create the file and save it as in small letters.

Answer (score 0):

It should be with small letters.

From the **[`Docs`](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide)**

> Do give the filename the conventional suffix (such as .component.ts,
>   .directive.ts, .module.ts, .pipe.ts, or .service.ts) for a file of
>   that type.

Comment: I am not creating any components and services or the directive, i just create the only ts file.thats why i am asking??

Comment: otherwise it is ok for component,directive and services

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea who makes up the names, but it looks like the filenames (Angular Guide) are in ['kebab-case'](http://wiki.c2.com/?KebabCase). So: All lowercase with - separating words.

(oh... and then they get an suffix as @sajeetharan mentioned)